# Unmanaged DLL call from C# works on PC with Visual Studio, not on PC without

Tags: c#

First of all, Stackoverflow has a lot of articles on unmanged DLLs, but my initial review of them did not show a solution to my issue.

I have a C# Winforms Application that uses a custom DLL that I have compiled from C++ Source code.

The project dependencies are Microsoft.NETCORE.App version 6.0.11 and Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11.

The DLL is included via the following code:

```
public const string CppFunctionsDLL = "CppFunctions.dll";

[DllImport(CppFunctionsDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern VCPCode getVCPCodeFromMonitor(byte vcpCode);

[DllImport(CppFunctionsDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool setVCPCodeFromMonitor(byte vcpCode, UInt32 newValue);
```

The methods from the DLL can then be called like a managed function. The "CppFunctions.dll" file is located in the same folder as the executable.

This works fine on my development PC and the functions from the DLL can be called. When I publish the code (with single file option enabled), I include the DLL in the same directory. This also works fine on my PC with Visual Studio installed. However, when I copy the .exe and .dll file to another PC that only has Microsoft.NETCORE.App version 6.0.12 and Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.12 installed, the app runs fine, but no DLL functions can be called. My development machine has .NET 5.0.410 and 7.0.100 SDKs installed, the other PC has no .NET SDKs installed.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

I build the DLL using this configuration:
[image: DLL settings]
For full clarity, this is my C++ code:

```c++
#include "Windows.h"
#include "PhysicalMonitorEnumerationAPI.h"
#include "lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")

const BYTE PowerMode = 0xD6;  // VCP Code defined in VESA Monitor Control Command Set (MCCS) standard
const DWORD PowerOn = 0x01;
const DWORD PowerOff = 0x05;
const DWORD PowerStandby = 0x04;

struct VCPCode
{
    BOOL VcpCodeReadSuccessfull;
    DWORD CurrentValue;
    DWORD MaxValue;
};
extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) VCPCode getVCPCodeFromMonitor(BYTE vcpCode)
    {
        VCPCode returnVCP = VCPCode();
        HMONITOR hMonitor = NULL;
        DWORD cPhysicalMonitors;
        LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitors = NULL;

        HWND hWnd = ::GetDesktopWindow();

        // Get the monitor handle.
        hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);

        // Get the number of physical monitors.
        BOOL bSuccess = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &cPhysicalMonitors);

        if (bSuccess)
        {
            // Allocate the array of PHYSICAL_MONITOR structures.
            pPhysicalMonitors = (LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR)malloc(cPhysicalMonitors * sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR));

            if (pPhysicalMonitors != NULL)
            {
                // Get the array.
                bSuccess = GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);

                // Get physical monitor handle.
                HANDLE hPhysicalMonitor = pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor;

                MC_VCP_CODE_TYPE pvct = MC_SET_PARAMETER;
                DWORD pdwCurrentValue = 0;
                DWORD pdwMaximumValue = 0;

                bSuccess = GetVCPFeatureAndVCPFeatureReply(hPhysicalMonitor, vcpCode, &pvct, &pdwCurrentValue, &pdwMaximumValue);
                returnVCP.VcpCodeReadSuccessfull = bSuccess;
                returnVCP.CurrentValue = pdwCurrentValue;
                returnVCP.MaxValue = pdwMaximumValue;

                // Close the monitor handles.
                bSuccess = DestroyPhysicalMonitors(cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);

                // Free the array.
                free(pPhysicalMonitors);
                return returnVCP;
            }
        }
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) BOOL setVCPCodeFromMonitor(BYTE vcpCode, DWORD newValue)
    {
        HMONITOR hMonitor = NULL;
        DWORD cPhysicalMonitors;
        LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitors = NULL;

        HWND hWnd = ::GetDesktopWindow();

        // Get the monitor handle.
        hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);

        // Get the number of physical monitors.
        BOOL bSuccess = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &cPhysicalMonitors);

        if (bSuccess)
        {
            // Allocate the array of PHYSICAL_MONITOR structures.
            pPhysicalMonitors = (LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR)malloc(cPhysicalMonitors * sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR));

            if (pPhysicalMonitors != NULL)
            {
                // Get the array.
                bSuccess = GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);

                // Get physical monitor handle.
                HANDLE hPhysicalMonitor = pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor;

                //Write VCP code to monitor
                bSuccess = SetVCPFeature(hPhysicalMonitor, vcpCode, newValue);

                if (bSuccess == FALSE)
                {
                    //std::cout << "Error setting VCP Code" << std::endl;
                    // Close the monitor handles.
                    bSuccess = DestroyPhysicalMonitors(cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);
                    // Free the array.
                    free(pPhysicalMonitors);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Close the monitor handles.
                    bSuccess = DestroyPhysicalMonitors(cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);

                    // Free the array.
                    free(pPhysicalMonitors);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception do you get? Maybe the DLL depends on other DLLs? You might get more information from the exception or from the Windows Event log.

Comment: Did you install VC redistributables on the PC without VisualStudio ?

Comment: It doesn't look like this unmanaged DLL has any dependency on other DLLs, beyond the C++ runtime support and DLLs provided by the OS.  So you can safely use Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > "Runtime library" = /MT for the Release configuration.  Rebuild and you'll now get a bigger file that includes the runtime support, linked into the .dll without additional deployment requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions. I have definitely learned a lot about managed/unmanaged code regarding runtime and deployment. I have only tried installing the VC redistributables, but that did the trick. I am definitely going to try to rebuild the DLL with the included runtime support, that sounds very interesting. Again, thank you for the help!